# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: string index out of range

Tags: java

I can't find an answer about this exception. THe program is very simple but, i don't know why is incorrect.

```
/**
 * Program selects the first word from the sentence "Hello, my dear!" with
 * the String Classes's methods this.indexOf() and this.substring()  
 * 
 *
 * Last modify: 29th October 2015
 */

public class TakeSubstringWanted {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sentence = "Hello, my dear!";
        String reference = "Hello";

        System.out.println("The sentence is: " + sentence);
        System.out.println("You want to take the first word of that sentence");
        System.out.println("Give me a second...");

        int firstReference = sentence.indexOf(reference);
        int firstLength = reference.length();
        System.out.println("The first reference of the searched word is " + firstReference);
        System.out.println("The first word of the sentence " + sentence + " is: " + "\"" + sentence.substring(firstReference, firstLength) + "\"");
        int secondReference = sentence.indexOf("my");
        System.out.println("The second reference of the searched word is " + secondReference);
        int secondLength = "my".length();
        System.out.println(secondLength);
        System.out.println(sentence);
        System.out.println("The second word of the sentence " + sentence + " is: " + "\"" + sentence.substring(secondReference, secondLength) + "\"");
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know what that Exception indicates?

Comment: `reference.length()` returns the length, but strings are zero-based. So you should use `substring` carefully..

Comment: show the complete stacktrace

Comment: @MarounMaroun: that is not the problem. The last index of substring is exclusive, so giving the length is no problem

Comment: @EmersonCod correct, thanks. But I hope OP understood the general idea :)

Comment: check the source of [substring](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.substring%28int%2Cint%29) then check the indexes passed in your last substring .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Problem is here:

```
sentence.substring(secondReference, secondLength)
```

Your giving to lengths but it should be

```
sentence.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in the last line:

```
System.out.println("The second word of the sentence " + sentence + " is: "
             + "\"" + sentence.substring(secondReference, secondLength) + "\"");
```

because your `secondReference = 7` and `secondLength = 2`, however if you look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) for `substring` method:

> public String substring(int beginIndex,
>                  int endIndex)
>
> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.
>
> ...
>
> **Throws:**
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex or endIndex are negative, if endIndex is greater than length(), or if beginIndex is greater than startIndex

Meaning, you're asking substring to return a string from index 7 to index 2, which causes an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. What you probably meant to do was:

```
sentence.substring(secondReference, secondReference + secondLength)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of substring is the end index, not the number of characters to take.

```
sentence.substring(secondReference, secondLength)
```

When you run this, secondLength is 2 (the length of "my"), but secondReference is 7, greater than 2, resulting in such an exception.

If you want those two characters, you'd need to use:

```
sentence.substring(secondReference, secondLength+secondReference)
```

Answer (score 0):

your last substring starts at pos 7 and the end index is 2, which is not possible. The last index is the end index, not the length of the char you like to take

```
sentence.substring(secondReference, seconfReference+secondLength);
```

would it be then

Answer (score 0):

when you are using **sentence.substring()** for second time the second  parameter of substring method should be greater than first parameter..in your case the first parameter is 7 and second parameter is 2 ...thats why you are getting String index out of range: -5

Answer (score -1):

Instead of giving the length, you have to give the end index. The substring method works like:

```
substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

Change

```
int firstLength = reference.length();
int secondLength = "my".length();
```

to

```
int firstLength = sentence.indexOf(",");
int secondLength = sentence.indexOf(" dear");
```

Try this:

```
String sentence = "Hello, my dear!";
String reference = "Hello";

System.out.println("The sentence is: " + sentence);
System.out.println("You want to take the first word of that sentence");
System.out.println("Give me a second...");

int firstReference = sentence.indexOf(reference);
int firstLength = sentence.indexOf(",");

System.out.println("The first reference of the searched word is " + firstReference);
System.out.println("The first word of the sentence " + sentence + " is: " + "\"" + sentence.substring(firstReference, firstLength) + "\"");

int secondReference = sentence.indexOf("my");

System.out.println("The second reference of the searched word is " + secondReference);

int secondLength = sentence.indexOf(" dear");

System.out.println(secondLength);
System.out.println(sentence);
System.out.println("The second word of the sentence " + sentence + " is: " + "\"" + sentence.substring(secondReference, secondLength) + "\"");
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show here? It is unclear if you dump code without explanation.

Comment: @AndyTurner Is that Okay now?

Comment: It is still unclear what you have actually changed in the code, because it is buried deeply inside all the other unchanged code.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks!! I have made those changes to my Answer. I think now everything is clear.

Comment: Clearer, but it is a brittle approach. This relies on knowing the string which follows `reference` and `"my"`, rather than just adding the length of those strings to the start index. And it is confusing to call something a length when it is an index.