# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, string

I know this error has been asked a lot. I have looked at them but still don't really understand how it applies to my problem. I am trying to write a program that creates a diamond pattern from a string.

```java
public static String nameDiamond(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    int i = 0;
    String out = "";
    while(i < len) { 
        out = out + s.substring(0, i + 1) + "\n";
        i++;
    }
    while(i > 0) { 
        int numSpaces = len - i + 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < numSpaces; j++)
            out = out + " ";
        out = out + s.substring(len - i + 1, i - 1) + "\n";
        i--;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Now my understanding of `substring` is, that it is structured like `s.substring(startIndex, endIndex)` and a cause of this error can be when the end index is less then the start but I don't think this is the problem here. I also saw some causes of the error is when something does not exist but again I don't think this is the problem. What am I missing?

When it is tested with "Marty" it says `-1` and with "Bill Nye" it says `-2`. Would the space be causing this?

I looked at lots of other versions of the questions but the ones that seemed relevent were:

[StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: string index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409160/stringindexoutofboundsexception-string-index-out-of-range)

[StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044470/stringindexoutofboundsexception-string-index-out-of-range-1)

But I don't think they apply.

For reference, this is the problem:
https://www.codestepbystep.com/problem/view/java/strings/nameDiamond

Comment: The problem is begin index > end index.

Comment: So that is my problem. End is less then the start. So biased on relevant link I have substring(secondReference, secondLength) when I should have substring(secondReference, secondLength+secondReference) and I should go substring(len - i + 1, len - i- 1)?

Comment: len - i + 1 is definitely always > len - i - 1

Comment: Oh the first one needs to be lower not greater.

Comment: Hey, @BENJAMINWEED . It would be great if you would include a copy of the error message in your question (formatted as a blockquote). It can help a lot in finding the underlying issue, especially in `Java` which has stacktraces.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one you can use as an example.  It doesn't do exactly what you want but it will illustrate one important thing.  For fixed width fonts, each row must be an odd number of characters.  Otherwise they won't line up properly.

If `n` is an even number, this particular version will print the same diamond for `n` and `n+1`.  It is also limited by the string of spaces.

```
public static void printDiamond(int len) {
    String str = "*";
    String space = "                              ";
    for (int i = 0; i < len/2 + 1; i++) {
        System.out.print(space.substring(0,len/2-i));
        System.out.println(str);
        str = str+"**";
    }
    str = str.substring(2);
    for(int i = 0; i < len/2; i++) {
        str = str.substring(2);
        System.out.print(space.substring(0,i+1));
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

As you debug your program, use ubiquitous print statements to print the different variables such as indices and string lengths.